# How to launch two similtanious C programs from within another program

Tags: c, multithreading

I am a beginner in C programming and my project is a multiplayer hangman game.

There are two roles in a round: the gamemaster enters the word and the player attempts to guess it. **These two programs need to run simultaneously in two terminal windows.** Both finish when the round is over.

So far so good. But now I would like to play a match consisting of multiple rounds. The program multiplayer.c asks for the number of rounds to be played and then the following is supposed to happen:

ROUND 1

launch gamemaster in terminal 1

launch player in terminal 2

ROUND 2

launch player in terminal 1

launch gamemaster in terminal 2

The thing is, gamemaster and player have to run simultaneously in two terminal windows and I need to be able to inverse the roles after each round.
I know that you can launch a script from within a C program like this: `int status = system("./foo 1 2 3");` but this syntax alone doesn't provide the solution.

Here's some code:

```
void main(){
    printf("Welcome to the multiplayer mode!\n");
    char nb_rounds;
    scanf("%d", &nb_rounds);

    int this_round=1;
    while(this_round<=nb_rounds){
        printf("Starting round %d!\n", this_round);
        if(this_round % 2 != 0){
            // launch gamemaster in Terminal 1 and player in Terminal 2
        }
        else{
            // inverse roles
            // launch player in Terminal 1 and gamemaster in Terminal 2
        }
        this_round++;
    }
}
```

I'm on Linux Ubuntu by the way.

Comment: This isn't even C#. It looks like C.

Comment: Johanna, please fix your title to not include dotnet.  How do you plan on having inter-process communication between those console windows and the main application that launched them?  Perhaps a different strategy is in order?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas-ReinstateMonica The programs player and gamemaster communicate via a fifo file. This works fine. They don't necessarily have to communicate with the main application.

Comment: If you need to start separate executables, then in `multiplayer.c`, use `fork()` to fork the process into two, then you can call `system()` in each fork separately (they will run in parallel), and in the parent process (where `fork()` returned a non-zero value), you then have to call `waitpid()` to wait for the child fork to complete. Then you can do the same for the second round.

Comment: @G.Sliepen If I do that, both player and gamemaster are executed in the same terminal window. But I absolutely need them to be in two separate windows.

Comment: So ensure a new terminal window is opened. If you are using the Gnome desktop, try: `system("gnome-terminal -- ./foo 1 2 3")`. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974756/how-can-i-open-a-extra-console-and-run-a-program-in-it-with-one-command) for more details.